# What is the proper way to run a javascript file in the background of a react native app?

Tags: react-native

I am writing a react native app and want to have a js file that listens to a server, fetches data from that server, and deploys changes to a redux store that updates my react components based off of the new data. I am curious, where is a proper place to instantiate this object that listens to the server? Currently, I am instantiating it in the top level component of my app like so...

[App File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZH16x.png)

In ControlBoard, I initialize the object...

[Control Board](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKXTe.png)

and then the DataModel responds to the server and updates the application state through redux.

I am running into problems with this approach (ie sometimes ControlBoard is constructed multiple times). Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

A a far better approach is to use [socket.io](https://socket.io/) to listen to any changes from your server then mapping it to your state and finally rendering it on whichever component you want.

There are many examples online to get you started, maybe you can look at [this](https://riptutorial.com/react-native/example/29846/web-socket-with-socket-io) and [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34) for a start